# At home Rochelle's salt synthesis

Tags: home-experiment

I tried to make Rochelle's salt. It didn't work!

- 7 oz cream of tartar
- 1 cup distilled water
- heat to 180 F and keep there
- add 1/2 tsp sodium carbonate at a time until there is no fizzing
- filter and let cool

The solution ended with a strong yellow/brown tint. It took at least an hour of adding sodium carbonate. While cooling it rapidly formed a crystallized honey look and that was it. I reheated and added more distilled water to lighten it up a bit thinking it needed to evaporate slower. This time when it cooled nothing happened.

The sodium carbonate was 100%, and the cream of tartar was McCormick. It's possible that came with some impurities hence the brown/yellow grossness.

Is there as way to save this batch? Should I just try again? Is there a better recipe?

My first instinct is that it didn't work because you don't science with Imperial units.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. If you have any questions about how the site works you can take the short [tour] or visit the [help]. Just one comment about your question: sometimes activated carbon is added to decolorize the solution prior to filtering. I don't know if this would make a difference in your situation though.

Comment: How are you judging "success" of this process?

Answer (score 1):

Tried again with 365 brand (whole foods) Cream of Tartar. Worked much better.

- 39g Cream of Tartar
- 50ml distilled water
- Sodium Carbonate added slowly until stirring produces clear liquid